# html2canvas works on desktop and iPadOS but not on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, html2canvas

I've been having this problem for a while now, the user of my website uploads an image and then the image is placed inside a template that has already been placed on the website.

When I try to use html2canvas on desktop, everything works, but when I tried to execute it on my iPhone, it didn't work and just resulted in an image.jpg.txt file.

Then, I tested it on my iPad just to figure out if the problem is with mobile devices or just iOS, and executing it on my iPad worked and resulted in an image file.

HTML:

```
    <div id="header">
        <a href="index.html" id="generalLink">General</a>
        <a href="page2.html" id="rehearsalLink">Page2</a>
    </div>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="imageUpload(event);" id="imageUpload">Upload Image</input>
    <div class="frameMain">
        <div id="frameContainer">
            <img src="images/generalFrame.png" alt="" class="frameImage">
            <div id="uploadedImage">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@latest/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
function imageUpload(event){
    if(event.target.files.length > 0){
      var src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      var preview = document.getElementById("uploadedImage");
      preview.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + src + ")";
    }
    
    let myElement = document.getElementById("frameContainer");
    console.log(myElement)

    html2canvas(myElement).then(canvas => {
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = 'image.jpg';
      link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      });
}
```